# Linux Mint 13 64bit Cinnamon and Oracle Virtualbox: 3d acceleration crash

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

I've recently got an interest in Linux. After some research, it looks like Linux Mint 13 cinnamon is hot and I thought I'd try it out...

I'm running Windows 7 64bit and have experience with Oracle Virtual Box. So I thought it would be a good idea to try out Linux Mint inside Virtual Box. I download Linux Mint 13 64bit Cinnamon and set it up in my VM player...

Nothing special about my settings. Except Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon requires 3d acceleration, and when I enable that, it crashes whenever I open the Menu in the bottom left corner of the guest OS (and some other times too)...

I've seen other mentions of this problem on the web, but no solutions. Is there a solution? If not, any suggestions short of installing the OS on a partition for trying out this OS (I'm not interested in the LIve mode either - I'd really like to get the full feel for it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install Linux Mint from Windows via wubi. There should be a .exe-file on the DVD which can be run to achieve this.

This installs Linux Mint in a virtual harddrive inside the windows partition.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I did eventually find this and it works. But running it on my real (laptop) hardware had its own problems (mouse, keyboard, gpu, ...), and I like the idea of experimenting with a new OS within a VM.

Comment: 3d acceleration inside a VM is very tricky and I don't know how to achieve this. Furthermore either there are no appropriate linux-drivers for your computer or you have to manually configure and install some drivers for everything on the real machine to work.

Comment: Eventually I found an excellent Ubuntu tutorial tailored for my exact machine and was able to get Mint dual-booting with Windows 7 with hardware issues solved. Hopefully the emergence of Linux Mint + Cinnamon as a popular distro will compel the Virtual Box guys to work out enough of the 3d acceleration kinks.

Comment: Good to hear that you had succes, nevertheless I think that there won't be any pressure on the Virtual Box Guys from Linux Mint with Cinnamon.

Comment: @Stephen I recently installed openSuSE with hardware accelerated GNOME 3 in VirtualBox on my Ubuntu and Aero in Windows 7 worked, too. So at least with Linux-Hosts, some graphics acceleration is possible (didn't try on windows).